# So the add-on builder has died. Any way to test an add-on without restarting FF every time?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I was using the add-on builder until today, now that it's dead I'm using the command-line tools. The problem with `cfx` is that every time I `run` it, FF is killed and restarted, I then need to go through my add-on's sign-in process every time and since it's a clean version of FF I can't even get it to remember my login details. Needless to say, going through these steps every time is a huge waste of time.

Given it's a restartless add-on that uses the add-on SDK, is there any way to reload the add-on without restarting FF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify source code without re-running cfx and Firefox when debugging an SDK add-on？](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519440/how-to-modify-source-code-without-re-running-cfx-and-firefox-when-debugging-an-s)

Comment: Yeah, I missed that on first search. Thanks for the good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/) by Wladimir Palant. It should give to you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I really recommend this. Once you have it working it's quite nice - just run a script and the extension is reloaded in a running Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Notes for others:  
- [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519440/how-to-modify-source-code-without-re-running-cfx-and-firefox-when-debugging-an-s)
- [Blog post with extension details](https://adblockplus.org/blog/faster-extension-development-cycle-install-changes-automatically)
- [How to install command line tools and `wget` pre-OSX 10.9](http://mikebeach.org/2012/09/29/how-to-install-wget-in-mac-os-x/)
- […on 10.9](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/2013/06/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cfx xpi`, then drag the file to Firefox to avoid restarting.
However, I suggest to just close the browser and specify a profile directory so that the state of the session is persisted across restarts:

```
cfx run --profiledir=/tmp/myprofile
```

or (Windows):

```
cfx run --profiledir=%TMP%\myprofile
```

(`-p` is a shorthand for `--profiledir`, so you can also use `cfx run -p/tmp/myprofile`)