# Restartless firefox extension using the SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've read in a couple of places e.g. [SDK vs XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/SDK_vs_XUL) and [Bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) that the SDK allows restartless extensions. However, I have no idea of how to do this! Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: As @JérémieBertrand said, all extensions made using the SDK are restartless.

Comment: @willlma Don't u have to run `cfx run` after every code change?

Comment: Yes, restartless just means that you don't need to restart the browser to install it. For dev/testing purposes, the browser is restarted for several reasons. If you don't want to restart the browser every time you change a line of code, check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519440/how-to-modify-source-code-without-re-running-cfx-and-firefox-when-debugging-an-s)

Comment: @willlma Ahh thanks for clearing 'restartless' up. Thank link is really helpful too!

Answer (score 2):

Just like it is indicated in the Bootstrapped extensions page you point, use the [Firefox Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) to create an extension.

Start with the [Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#getting-started) part: installation and first creation of an extension with the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The best page that I can recommend for now is [Getting Started with jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29).

Comment: Can't wait until we can merge this back officially into MDN.